# What happens to Deposits when purchasing stock shares or money market fund shares?

Tags: macroeconomics, stock-market, money-supply

I'm trying to understand the flow of money into the shadow banking sector, e.g. what happens when deposits are transferred to either a brokerage, or a money market mutual fund (MMMF), and specifically how M2 reflects that movement.

##### Deposit moves into a brokerage:

My assumption is that, when you send money to a brokerage, something like the following occurs:

- Your bank reduces your deposit balance and their reserve balance, sending funds to the brokerage's bank
- Brokerage has your money in their bank.  I assume this is a combined account of sorts where they track each customer's portion of the deposit balance.
- If you make a purchase of stock, they lower their deposit balance and send funds to the seller's brokerage.  You are credited with shares for your purchase
- Seller's bank receives deposits/reserves from buyer's bank (your brokerage's bank), and credits their customer's account (the seller).

In this situation, M2 never leaves the system, it just moves between different brokerage's bank account's depending on who is buying and who is selling.  Cash balances shown in your brokerage are effectively held in a combined account, and your claim on those balances is what you see in your brokerage report.

##### Deposit moves into MMMF:

I assume the situation is similar, but the shares are money market shares instead of stock shares.  What I'm not certain on, is how M2 avoids double counting deposits / shares associated with MMMF.

- MMMF receives a deposit/reserve from your bank
- They use these funds to make investments
- When they make investments, they send deposits at their bank account to the sellers account
- Just like the brokerage example, M2 never leaves the system, it just moves around

However, since MMMF *shares* are counted as part of M2, is double counting an issue since the deposits used to initially purchase the shares never actually leave the system?